# Setting up an access point

Tags: linux, wifi

I have a laptop with an Atheros card and I woud like to use it as a wireless access point.

I need an AP with WPA/WPA2 encryption for testing purposes; I don't need any routing functionality or anything else (it's fine if it has that, but it's not a requirement).

A live CD would be good, I just want something that's easy to setup -- like I mentioned, it's not for real use. I tried it on Ubuntu but I guess by default Ubuntu is missing the special drivers required to act as an access point.

Comment: I ended up using Windows 7 and virtual wifi (google that). quite easy and microsoft forces drivers to already include the necessary functions :-)

Comment: which atheros card do you have? lspci output? 11abg or 11n?

Comment: I don't know, but the windows 7 solution works great for me, so my problem is solved ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For posterity sake, the best way to create an AP is using the `hostapd` program, which is available [here](http://hostap.epitest.fi/hostapd/) and prepackaged in many distros.

In Debian or derivatives, the packages comes with a file `/usr/share/doc/hostapd/examples/hostapd.conf.gz`, which is an example configuration. You need to copy the file to a different directory (your `$HOME`, for example), decompress it (`gunzip hostapd.conf.gz`) and then edit the `hostapd.conf` file with any text editor.

Search for the line which says `WPA/IEEE 802.11i configuration`. The file is well docummented, but for a simple WPA2 AP you just need to:

- change the line `interface=wlan0` to match your card's interface
- (optional) change the line `ssid=test` to `ssid=NetworkNameOfChoice`
- uncomment the line `#wpa=1` to `wpa=1`
- uncomment the line which says `#wpa_passphrase=secret passphrase` and change the passphrase.

Save the file and then on a terminal run `sudo ifconfig wlan0 192.168.3.1` (replacing `wlan0` with your card's interface) and `sudo hostapd hostapd.conf`. A new network should appear with the chosen name (or 'test' if you didn't change it).

(Note: the network will let anyone with the right passphrase connect, but it won't give it an IP address. If you want that you should ask how to set up a testing dhcp server).

Comment: that looks quite simple, though the windows version is even easier ;-) but a very good record for linux users and the archive, tahnk you!

Comment: @stefan.at.wpf: there might be some graphical interface to hostapd, but I wouldn't know. Glad you've found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `wifi-ap` for that.

`wifi-ap` is a snap package that will help you easily create an access point via terminal. All you have to do is to install it with the command `sudo snap install wifi-ap`, then call it from terminal like this `wifi-ap.config` to configure your access point.