# Access point (with hostapd) on the same interface as the network/gateway?

Tags: linux, networking, wifi

I wonder if it should be possible to have an wireless access point using hostapd (as described in [Set up an access point](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13747/set-up-an-access-point)) on the same interface that connects to a wireless network for internet.

I have a working setup where hostapd runs on wlan0 and I can use the internet from eth0 - so internet and AP are on different interfaces/devices.

The wireless card is a Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6205 card.

Should this be possible given this hardware in general?

Answer (score 1):

There are WiFi cards that can act as both a station and as an AP. I've heard that there are Atheros cards that are capable of doing that, however I have not been able to obtain one to test it out with.

I don't think the Intel Centrino devices are able to do it however.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. You would need two wireless cards.

Answer (score 0):

As it is said in Richard Hum's answer you can not configure one interface to be both AP and WiFi client. However I think that what you are trying to do is bridging between your ethernet interface and your wireless interface.

For the question, yes, it is possible. In order to achieve that you need:

- Configure your `wlan0` interface to run as a AP (explained in the link you wrote)
- Connect you `eth0` to internet
- Then establish a bridge (a virtual connection) between the wireless interface in which hostapd should be running. A very documented guide of how to do it can be found in [here](https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections)

The schema would be:

> INTERNET <-> `eth0` <-virtual connection-> `wlan0` <-> wifi_clients

This is as for the software. As for the hardware the WiFi need to support AP wireless mode (you can see the different modes [here](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Documentation/modes#AccessPoint_.28AP.29_infrastructure_mode) )

I have taken a overview through the tech specs of your card and it supports it